# WHERE IF (field depends of parameter) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

Example of initial data:

```
 Project   |   Field1   |   Field2    |   Field3    |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
 Project 1 |      0     |      1      |      2      |
 Project 2 |      2     |      0      |      1      |
```

Using SQL Server 2014, I have table, where I need to get data which depends of value in ssrs parameter. Sample of query.

```
Select *
Where IF@Scenario=1, then Field1 < 2
      IF@Scenario=2, then Field2 < 2
      IF@Scenario=3, then Field3 < 2
From Table1
```

Comment: Please show us what your expected output is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select *
FROM x
Where 
      2 > 
      CASE @Scenario WHEN 1 THEN Field1 
           WHEN 2 THEN Field2
           WHEN 3 THEN Field3
           ELSE 0 --This part is just to avoid errors when scenario isnt in any of the options. 2>0 will display everything
      END
```

Compare the condition (2) with the columns instead.

Comment: In this case is it possitble to use multiple fields ?  
with sample like:
      WHEN 1 THEN Field 1 and Field2
      WHEN 2 THEN Field 3 and Field4 and etc.

Comment: No. You'd have to add another condition on the where clause for that... Something like ....AND (2 > CASE @Scenario WHEN 3 THEN Field4 ELSE 2-1 END) (I think it's safer to use VALUE-1 instead of 0 if your where condition can possibly be negative. i.e. if 2 can be -1 so your else condition would be -1-1 (-2)

Answer (score 1):

Use `AND/OR` conditions

```
Select *
From Table1
Where (@Scenario=1 and Field1 < 2) Or 
      (@Scenario=2 and Field2 < 2) Or
      (@Scenario=3 and Field3 < 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE Statement in WHERE cluase :

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE CASE @Scenario WHEN 1 THEN Field1 
       WHEN 2 THEN Field 2
       WHEN 3 THEN Field 3
       ELSE 0 END < 2
```